# Ninject: ConstructorArgument doesnt work

Tags: ninject, ninject-2

I use NInject "2.2.0.0". I have a class ShellView which has 2 constructors:

```
public ShellView()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}

public ShellView(IScreen screen)
  : this()
{           
    this.DataContext = screen;
}
```

I call it with:

```
Kernel.Get<Views.ShellView>(new Ninject.Parameters.ConstructorArgument("IScreen", shellViewModel));
```

But it calls always "ShellView()" without calling "ShellView(IScreen screen)" :-/

I found several examples in google where it sheems to work - what have i done wrong?

Comment: Try changing "IScreen" in your ConstructorArgument call to "screen"?

Comment: Damn - was sitting to long in front of the monitor :-S

Sorry for spam :-/

Comment: Since this question has already been answered by a comment, I'm voting to close as Too Localized.